# Firebase OnTokenReceived Doesn't Get Triggered in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need to set up FCM for push notification in my unity game. For that, I am using initializing code which is mentioned in the Firebase docs which is:

```
public void Start() {
  Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.TokenReceived += OnTokenReceived;
  Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.MessageReceived += OnMessageReceived;
}

public void OnTokenReceived(object sender, Firebase.Messaging.TokenReceivedEventArgs token) {
  UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Received Registration Token: " + token.Token);
}

public void OnMessageReceived(object sender, Firebase.Messaging.MessageReceivedEventArgs e) {
  UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Received a new message from: " + e.Message.From);
}
```

The game uses GameSparks for back-end services. I want to notify user for New High Score in the leaderboard. To do that I have to register device for push notification and according to GameSparks's documentation the following code is used to register push:

```
  new PushRegistrationRequest()
        .SetDeviceOS(deviceOS)
        .SetPushId(pushId)
        .Send((response) => {
        string registrationId = response.RegistrationId; 
        GSData scriptData = response.ScriptData; 
        });
```

The `pushId` is taken from is the registration id returned from the call to `FirebaseInstanceID.getToken()` as mentioned [here](https://docs2.gamesparks.com/tutorials/social-features/configuring-firebase-cloud-messaging.html). Did I do something wrong here? If there is a better solution please tell me that too. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Need more details. Do you receive OnTokenReceived log?

Comment: @Deepscorn Actually in editor it doesn't get called. But on device it does called. Sorry for not posting the answer before. I was busy.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not building and running the Unity Project on an Android Device you will not receive a token. If you're running it on your device and are connected to your computer you can check if the log message is triggered using:

`adb logcat -s Unity`